# Blocking While Waiting For C# Event In Powershell Causes Deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, powershell

In PowerShell, I'm attempting to start a process, and wait until either the process exits, or the script gets a signal from a named pipe. While the named pipe components work fine, the code is failing to process events when the script is blocked. Here's an example of just the event-related code:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# launch process with the appropriate args. 
$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::new() 
$p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe" 
$p.StartInfo.Arguments = $null 
$p.EnableRaisingEvents = $true $p.Start()

# create a task completion source
$tcs = [System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource[Boolean]]::new()

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $p -EventName Exited `
    -MessageData $tcs `
    -Action {
        $Event.MessageData.SetResult($true)
    } 

# wait for the program to exit 
$processTask = $tcs.Task

# this deadlocks 
$processTask.Wait()
```

Is there a correct way to solve this problem, either via PowerShell's job system, or by manually spinning up another C# task that waits for the process to exit, that would allow the script to resume once either events occurs?

For reference, here's the more complete script (which includes the wait on either the process event or named pipe):

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

#inbound pipe
$pipeListener = [System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream]::new("testPipe", 1) 

# launch process with the appropriate args.
$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::new()
$p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe"
$p.StartInfo.Arguments = $null
$p.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
$p.Start()

# I would normally solve this using a TaskCompletionSource
# in C#, and have it fire off the process's exited event.

# create a task completion source
$tcs = [System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource[Boolean]]::new()

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $p -EventName Exited `
    -MessageData $tcs `
    -Action {
        $Event.MessageData.SetResult($true)
    } 

# wait for the program to exit, or for pipe signal
try {
    $pipeTask = $pipeListener.WaitForConnectionAsync()
    $processTask = $tcs.Task

    while ($true)
    {
        echo "Launched Process, waiting for sequence to complete..."

        # this works, but not instantly - the timeout appears to allow the 
        # event to process.
        #$res = [System.Threading.Tasks.Task]::WaitAny(@($processTask, $pipeTask), 10000)

        # this does not.
        $res = [System.Threading.Tasks.Task]::WaitAny(@($processTask, $pipeTask))


        echo "Got wait result: $res"

        if ($pipeTask.IsCompleted) {
            echo "Got pipe connection"
            $sr = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($pipeListener)
            $msg = $sr.ReadToEnd()

            echo "Pipe sent: $msg"
            break
        }

        if ($processTask.IsCompleted) {
            echo "Process completed."
            break
        }
    }
}
finally {
    $pipeListener.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Note that it doesn't seem to be related to named pipe. Even if you wait only on `$processTask` (`$processTask.Wait()`) and remove all the code relative to named pipes, you'll run into the same issue. It looks like powershell is trying to raise the event on the main thread, which causes a deadlock since it's blocked waiting on the task. Unfortunately, I know almost nothing about powershell's threading model so I cannot help you further. But I suspect the question will attract more people if you remove any mention of named pipes and make your code simpler/shorter

Comment: @KevinGosse - I was worried not including it would create confusion over why I was using C# events/processes and not powershell functions, but I see your point. I've modified the question so it hopefully better captures the problem while still including context. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, this doesn't appear possible - PowerShell only processes C# events in the main thread, even if the source of the event is a background thread.

Additionally, the PowerShell job system uses processes, not threads, for each job, so you can't set the Task Completion Source from a background job.

However, C# code called from PowerShell works normally, and can spawn threads. So, to solve this problem, I wrote a C# function that, when a process dies, send a message to a named pipe:

```
    public static void NotifyPipeOnProcessExit(
        Process processToMonitor,
        String pipeName
    )
    {
        // Create a pipe client.
        var client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipeName, PipeDirection.Out);

        // create a process task
        var processTask = Task.Run(() => {
            processToMonitor.WaitForExit();

            using (client)
            {
                client.Connect(0);
                var sw = new StreamWriter(client);
                sw.Write("Process exitted.");
                sw.Close();
            }

        });

        return;
    }
```

Then I simply called this function in PowerShell to attach the process object to the pipe:

```
[ThreadTool.ThreadHelper]::NotifyPipeOnProcessExit($p, $pipeName)

$pipeListener.WaitForConnection()
```

This also simplifies the code, since the PowerShell now only needs to monitor a single event.

That said, the C# code could have just as easily set a TaskCompletionSource instead of sending a message through the named pipe.